# Change Fill Color or strokeColor for Vector Layout Programmatically

Tags: java, android

Changing stroke or fill color using programmatically. Is it possible to change fill color of vector programmatically but not stroke color.

> vector_icon.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        android:strokeWidth="0.8"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeMiterLimit="1"
        android:pathData="M12,22c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2h-4c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2zM18,16v-5c0,-3.07 -1.64,-5.64 -4.5,-6.32L13.5,4c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v0.68C7.63,5.36 6,7.92 6,11v5l-2,2v1h16v-1l-2,-2z"/>

</vector>
```

Image view where i used vector drawable.

```
   <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivNotification"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_icon_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_icon_size"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/vector_icon_notification"/>
```

I have tried to cast VectorDrawable to GradientDrawable but it throws class cast execption.

```
GradientDrawable gdFavourite = (GradientDrawable) ivFavourite.getDrawable();
                gdFavourite.setStroke(1, colorPrimary);
                gdFavourite.setColor(colorPrimary);
                tvFavourite.setTextColor(colorPrimary);
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [animated vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#AnimVector) are for? Why aren't you using one of those?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have many options here, you just need to accept the fact that `ivFavourite.getDrawable();` returns `VectorDrawable` and it does not allows you to change the Storke via code.

You can see the full doc of this class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

One possible solution to work arround it, is to get the VectorDrawable from other xml and override the existen one by calling: `ivFavourite.setBackgroundDrawable(myVectorDrawable)`

Comment: changing BackgroundDrawable for imageview i need to create two drawable any-other option ?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav You can set the backgroundDrawable to what ever you like, but if you set it via xml, you need to cast it to what you set, if it's a VectorDrawable, there is no magic way to transport it to be LayerDrawable